# Room request, one to many relathionship

Tags: java, android, database, rx-java, android-room

## Given

I have two classes, '**inspection**' and '**items**,' which have a one-to-many relationship, meaning one inspection can have many items, and each item is associated with a single inspection."

and I'm storing them as tables in a ROOM local database, they look like this:

### Inspection

```
@Entity(tableName = "vehicle_inspection")
public class VehicleInspectionDB {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long inspectionDBId;
...
....
```

### Item

```
@Entity(tableName = "inspection_item")
public class VehicleInspectionItemDB {


@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long itemDBId;
private long inspectionDBId;
...
....
```

I created this class in order to retrieve the inspections and the items associated:

### Inspection with items class

```
public class InspectionAndItemsDB {
@Embedded
public VehicleInspectionDB inspection;
@Relation(
parentColumn = "inspectionDBId",
entityColumn = "itemDBId"
)
public List<VehicleInspectionItemDB> items;
}
```

and this Dao method:

### DAO method

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_inspection")
Flowable<List<InspectionAndItemsDB>> getInspectionAndItems();
```

## The problem

when I use that method above get inspection and items
I'm receiving only one child per parent it is only one item in the list per inspection instead of a list containing all the items associated with that inspection.

What's the issue? I've followed this tutorial by a google member:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `InspectionAndItemsDB` class, in the `@Relation` annotation, you should change it to:

```java
public class InspectionAndItemsDB {
    @Embedded
    public VehicleInspectionDB inspection;
    
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "inspectionDBId",  // Primary key (parent entity)
        entityColumn = "inspectionDBId"   // Foreign key (child entity)
    )
    public List<VehicleInspectionItemDB> items;
}
```

The value of `entityColumn` will be matched against the value defined in `parentColumn()`, so you should consider this. See: [*Relation Docs*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation#entitycolumn)